# Passing image URL to view from controller

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

I am currently stuck with a situation where I cant get the right line to pass through to make the image show, this is what I have so far:

Controller

```
    // Get image URL and alternate text
        $image_filename = "<?php echo base_url('assets/imgs/'". $code ."'.png'); ?>";           
        $page_data['image_filename'] = $image_filename;
        $image_alt = 'Image: ' . $code . '.png';
        $page_data['image_alt'] = $image_alt;

        $this->load->view('common/header'); 
        $this->load->view('top_nav');
        $this->load->view('shop_viewprod', $page_data);
        $this->load->view('common/footer');         
    }
```

I have to find the image for the product selected that's why I have to use the $code variable, cause it will always change and that's how I get the code for the current item selected.

And then the view

```
    <img src="<?php echo $image_filename; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image_alt; ?>" />
```

The path to the image is:

assets\imgs\name.png

The thing is, if I do use this in the view, it finds the image

```
   <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/imgs/fg700s.png'); ?>  " alt="<?php echo $image_alt; ?>" />
```

Just to show you the two side by side in the code

```
    <img src="<?php echo $image_filename; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image_alt; ?>" />
    <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/imgs/fg700s.png'); ?> " alt="<?php echo $image_alt; ?>" />
```

and the result:[image: Result]

So I reckon its the way I make the image_filename variable and how I use it in the view, but I cant understand what it is I am missing?

Can anyone help me solve this please?

Comment: Just wanted to comment, my model, view and controller all work seamlessly together, its only the image url I have a problem with.

Comment: what does `var_dump( $page_data);` gives you update question with it's result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I played around with it alil more and came up with this:

In the controller:

```
    $page_data['code'] = $code;         
    $image_alt = 'Image: ' . $code . '.png';
    $page_data['image_alt'] = $image_alt;
```

In the View

```
    <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/imgs/'.$code.'.png'); ?>" alt="<?php echo $image_alt; ?>" />
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the variable(s) to the view.

When you load your view, you are passing a variable, probably `$data`, to the `$this->load->view()` function as the *second* parameter.

It is probably an array.

You should set a key like `$data['image_filename'] = base_url[...];` **before** loading the view.

Comment: I have updated the code, I do pass variables through to the view, I can confirm that, as I said its only the image I'm struggling with getting to show, I will try your solution about the array in alil but :) and let you know!